# Material-dialogs dependency error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Im using

```
dependencies {
    //[...] other dependencies omitted here
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.8.5.2'
}
```

within my `build.gradle`. Running `$ gradle clean build` gets me

```
[...] much output omitted
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library
:prepareOsmbonuspack_v53Library
:prepareDebugDependencies
Module 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.8.5.2' depends on one or more  Android Libraries but is a jar
:prepareDebugDependencies FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':prepareDebugDependencies'.
> Dependency Error. See console for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.045 secs
```

So the problem seems to be *Module 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.8.5.2' depends on one or more  Android Libraries but is a jar* but [searching the web for a solution](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Module+depends+on+one+or+more+Android+Libraries+but+is+a+jar&t=ffab) did not help.

How can I fix that dependency error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```